# Vagrant -- E: Couldn't determine free space

Tags: vagrant, apt-get

Yesterday my vagrant box was working fine.  Now it's not.  When I try to provision my box again, or run this command (or any apt-get):

> sudo /usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install postgresql

I get this error:

> E: Couldn't determine free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/ - statvfs (20: Not a directory)

I've:

- done a destroy, and I still get this error.
- removed all but a couple packages from my provisioner I still get this error.
- created a new vagrant file, using the same box, and I do NOT get this error.
- cloned my vagrant file into a new folder, and I still get this error.

What is going on here?

UPDATE: It looks like there is a lock file in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the `vagrant-cachier` pluggin, and it had cached a bad apt-get request that put in a lock.  When I disabled this pluggin and rebuild the machine there were no issues.